# Python Dataframe Single Row with Label

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = ["X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B"]
label = ['a','b','c','d','e']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=label)
print(df)
```

I want to get the dataframe to be:

```
a b c d e 
X Y Z A B
```

I am getting

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 5), indices imply (5, 5)
```

How to fix this to get the desired dataframe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it as a list of list.

```
In [439]: pd.DataFrame([data], columns=label)
Out[439]:
   a  b  c  d  e
0  X  Y  Z  A  B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bit complicated, but very fast solution if large data - convert list to `numpy array` and then [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).reshape(-1, len(data)), columns=label)
print(df)
   a  b  c  d  e
0  X  Y  Z  A  B
```

**Timings**:

```
N = 100
data = ["X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B"] * N
label = ['a','b','c','d','e'] * N

In [30]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([data], columns=label)
10 loops, best of 3: 178 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).reshape(-1, len(data)), columns=label)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 ms per loop

N = 1000

In [35]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([data], columns=label)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.7 s per loop

In [36]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).reshape(-1, len(data)), columns=label)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.83 ms per loop
```